# Sequential and running in one thread time difference c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is my source code for testing multithread performance in C++. Please tell me why is time about 5x smaller for ONE thread running(WaitForMultipleObject()) then first sequential performance. I expect almost same result for sequential performance and running with only one thread. Thanks

http://pastebin.com/EeJ5qW03

Comment: Please rewrite your question in proper english: I can't understand what are you asking.

Answer (score 2):

OS will decide when will your thread start running and it will also decide if there's a need for dispatching, perhaps. Add to that, it also has to create a separate stack for your thread, perhaps.

Read about the overhead on thread creation. All in all, the overhead is system specific.

Comment: yup, basically your problem size isn't large enough to benefit from multithreading and actually makes it take longer